# Copy new (changed) files into repository

Tags: macos, svn

I have a magento project that I'm managing under subversion version control.

I want to install a module that I downloaded which modifies some core files that are already under svn.

When I copy the new files over the existing managed ones, the repo becomes 'obstructed':

> svn: Directory '/foo/app/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing

What's the proper way to manage bringing in code from outside the repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure not to delete any .svn directory when you copy the new files into your working copy (unless of course you want to delete the repository containing this .svn directory). A simple way to do that is to keep all the directories as is, and only delete and update files.

Alternatively, use SVN 1.7, which uses a single .svn directory at the root of the project instead of a .svn directory in every directory of the project.

Comment: Oddly enough, my copy operation was not just adding missing files, but deleting the folders and recreating (which deleted my .svn directories). File-by-file moving, while inefficient, fixed it.